# How to restrict the focus of JFrame in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

I have a parent `JFrame` it contain a `JButton`. functionality of that button is to open another window.

I want to restrict the focus of window, means after closing the second window's focus should come into first window(parent).  And focus should not come to first window if second window is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your second window [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window).  That said, you'd probably want to make it a [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29).

Comment: +1 an application should only have single parent JFrame and then use JDialog's as child windows.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible but workaround for two or more [JFrames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), but for full funcionalities is needed lots of code,

standard would be one JFrame and another [TopLayoutContainers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) could be [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) then you can easily play with [parent and modalities](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Window,%20java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29), [toFront](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29) , [setAlwaysOnTop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

As shinoku stated, you can use a modal. However if you have to use a JFrame, you have to implement a `WindowListener` for the new `JFrame`. In that implementation for the `windowClosing()` method you can say `originalJFrame.requestFocus()`. Of course, your constructor of the `WindowListener` must be supplied with a reference to the original frame as well.